# Editing files in clearcase view

Tags: tcl, clearcase

I have previously worked with CVS where i used to open my TCL script with IDE like editplus, recently I have to shift to clearcase environment., where when we set view alone , we can see our files., how can i open and edit those files in IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file using the full path of said file in the ClearCase view.

In a snapshot view, that path is a regular filesystem path:

```
# Windows
c:\path\to\snap\view\AVob\path\to\file

# Unix
/path/to/snap/view/vobs/Avob/path/to/file
```

But with dynamic view, that view is mounted in a MVFS (MultiVersion FileSystem) mount point (M:/ on Windows, /view on Unix)

```
# Windows
M:\aDynView\AVob\path\to\file

# Unix
/view/aDynView/vob/vobs/AVob/path/to/file
```

On Unix, you can also "set the view" ([`cleartool setview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66)), which would make your view starts in `/vobs`:

```
/vobs/AVob/path/to/file
```

Comment: My file path will be /abc/cde/fgh/ijk.tcl,  which location will not be available until i set the view via "cleartool setview <my_view>" , so how can i open above location in Editplus or ultraedit ?

Comment: @RamanathanPalaniappan do not use `setview`. It generally brings trouble. Use the full dynamic view path: `/view/aDynView/vobs/abc/cde/fgh/ijk.tcl`

Comment: Thanks!!, for me its right there in /view/<my_view>/<file path>, so i dont have it under vobs , is it ok?

Comment: @RamanathanPalaniappan it is perfect: that looks like the full path of a view to me.